# Problem with exercism.io python track test/submit process

Tags: python

I have registered with exercism.io on the Python track, and haven't got off to a good start!  The first exercise is a simple print hello world example, and I am of course able to write the code that executes this. The problem I have is where on earth do I place my code? Should I overwrite the existing hello_world.py file with my own file, or add my script lines to the existing file?  I have read the documentation and must be missing something as I can't fathom out what to do with my code to test and submit.

When I download the test material, there is a default hello.world.py file created in the relevant directory, which contains this;

```
def hello():
    pass
```

There is also a hello_world_test.py that contains this;

```
import unittest

import hello_world


# Tests adapted from `problem-specifications//canonical-data.json` @ v1.1.0

class HelloWorldTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_hello(self):
        self.assertEqual(hello_world.hello(), 'Hello, World!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I have written a file called exercism_hello_world.py which contains this;

```
# This script prints "Hello, World!" to the console

print ("Hello, World!")

# end of script
```

Can anyone who may already be using exercism.io please advise how / where I place my code so that I can test / submit the first exercise and continue with the learning.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the Exercism directory to begin with a capital "E" if you're running on macOS.

Try out:

exercism submit /Users/(your username)/Exercism/python/hello-world/hello_world.py

Answer (score 2):

After installing the cli script. 
Enter the file location of full python file along with the name of the file.

Example

```
exercism submit C:\Users\srag\Exercism\python\hello-world\hello_world.py
```

Comment: I am in the exercism/python/hello-world directory, and when I type exercism submit hello_world.py I get Error: Not in workspace

Comment: enter full file location along with the file name. not just the file name.

Comment: OK, I should also mention I am on a Mac... so what would that make the full path?  I tried exercism submit users/John/exercism/python/hello-world/hello_world.py and get Error: 

    The file you are trying to submit cannot be found.

        /Users/john/exercism/python/users/john/exercism/python/hello-world/hello_world.py

Comment: try out with path /users/John/exercism/python/hello-world/hello_world.py instead of users/John/exercism/python/hello-world/hello_world.py

Comment: Alas still no joy - so frustrating.  Very sorry I am not doing very well here @sree. Thanks for your help.  if I include the / at the start of the path I get Error: not in workspace, and if I leave the / out at the start of the path I get the longer error listed above.

Comment: WhenI am in the exercism/python/hello-world directory, doing ls shows that my hello_world.py file is present.  Yet when in that directory, I type exercism submit hello_world.py I get Error: not in workspace

Comment: OK... going to my home directory and typing exercism submit Exercism/python/hello-world/hello_world.py worked.  What on earth...?????

Answer (score 0):

You should add your solution to the `hello_world.py` file.

However, you can change the default Exercism workspace directory. If you are on MacOS or Unix you can do that via terminal:

```
exercism configure --workspace="YOUR_PATH"
```

By changing this setting, everytime you run the command to "clone" the problem, it will get copied to the path you specified.

Regarding this problem, I am not sure if it helps, but it was stated to return "Hello, World!" and not print it.